# Microsoft Azure Load Test tool : Testing Privately Hosted Apps

Tags: azure, load-testing, preview

We are evaluating new "Microsoft Azure Load Test tool" as an alternative to currently used load testing tool in our project. As per information available with us, currently this tool can test only publicly hosted apps and does not support load testing of applications hosted within private networks. We wanted to check(if anyone else is also exploring this tool), if there can be any option of exposing privately hosted test environments with secure access (using some gateway/firewall configurations/Private IPs) to enable this tool to interact with privately hosted apps.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it is not about programming.

Comment: You can now use Azure Load Testing to also test privately hosted endpoints. There is support for apps hosted in Azure VNETs, endpoints hosted on-premises but connected via ExpressRoute, or public endpoints that have IP-address allowlisting.
Here's more info on how to set it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-test-private-endpoint